# Coldfusion comments and IE conditional comments

Tags: coldfusion, comments, conditional-comments

Do you use two (HTML comments) or three (ColdFusion comments) dashes for inline IE conditional statements in a .cfml file?

Example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>..do something..</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I am pretty sure the code is the same regardless of whether it is in an HTML file or CFML file.  Can anyone validate?  Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you tried with `<! - - - `?

Comment: Did you even try to figure this out on your own? It would have take you less time to test both ways than to post this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could have been resolved by simply *trying it* and observing the results. If the results were then confusing, *that* is what the question should have been about.

Comment: Yes, it could have been figured out by trying both versions of the comments... IF I had been able to run a snippet on a ColdFusion server.  At the time I did not have access to one and a client was reaching out to me in regards to an issue which they were convinced it had something to do with the IE conditionals.  I was almost certain I knew the correct format but it has been a long while since I have done any Coldfusion, and in turn why I asked the question knowing it would take less than a minute for someone to offer reassurance.  Any thing else of the whole story needed?

Comment: @DougHill nice story bro. However this kinda demonstrates even you didn't really think this would be a good question for StackOverflow, which is an exercise in asking (and answering) questions that would be useful for *other developers*. For future reference, either cflive.net or trycf.com will let you try this sort of thing *online*, and the Adobe ColdFusion forums are probably a better fit for this sort of of one-off help requests.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the site references, didn't know they even existed. And you are correct, I didn't put much weight into how strict and rigid the Q&A format is on this site.  Guess that's the best way learn the etiquette, by asking and answering once each. :)  Well, enough wasted energy on everyone's part... blast or vaporize this post / question, or do whatever it is you moderators do when someone breaks the law!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coldfusion comments (3 dashes) will not be included in the output that is sent to the browser. So you'll have to use regular html comments (2 dashes).

Comment: Why is it important for comments to be sent to the browser?

Comment: Well in this case, these comments contain instructions only meaningful for (and to be executed on) a webbrowser.